# AVAudioEngine changes other app's output route

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I'm seeing an unexpected effect with `AVAudioEngine` that I'm trying to get my head around. The route of another app's audio playback changes from the speaker to the earpiece when my app's engine starts. I want the other app to keep playing out of the speaker.

Here's how to reproduce.

Make an empty app and add the `UnexpectedAudio` class below. In your `ViewController` class add and initialize an `unexpected` property (`let unexpected = UnexpectedAudio()`), and then add a button to your storyboard that calls `unexpected.start()`.

```
class UnexpectedAudio {    
  let engine: AVAudioEngine

  init() {
    self.engine = AVAudioEngine()
    _ = engine.inputNode // lazily creates node
  }

  func start() {
    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                                                     mode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault,
                                                     options: [.mixWithOthers])
    try! engine.start()
  }
}
```

Run the app, but don't press the button yet. Then with no headphones plugged in, jump over to Apple Music and play a song. It should come out the speaker. Now, switch back to your app and press the button. For me, this makes the Apple Music audio switch back to the earpiece.

Any idea why this might be happening? And how I can prevent the route change? Thanks!